# Aguardar tempo para executar nova ação [Selenium] [C#]

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Estou começando com automação de testes com o *Selenium WebDriver* na linguagem **C#**.
Estou com uma dúvida, tenho que fazer o teste esperar a página carregar para executar uma nova ação. Como faço isso? 
Acredito que o mais fácil é fazer por tempo. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

Há 4 formas de esperar.

Implicitamente, é aplicavel para todos os elementos da pagina.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(ALGUM_NUMERO, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Explicitamente, aplicado para um elemento particular.

```
WebDriverWait.until(CONDICAO_QUE_BATE_COM_O_ELEMENTO);
```

E para casos mais específicos.

```
WebDriverWait espera = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
WebElement element = espera.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("algumid")));
```

Usando thread.

```
Thread.sleep(NUMBER_OF_MILLIS);
```

[@fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377384/how-to-wait-a-page-before-going-to-another-page-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

Caso concreto de uso, aguardando tempo de execução para executar nova ação:

O formulário base que escrevi o teste exigia fornecer nome e email para submeter. O teste verifica se o nome foi fornecido após submit, comparando a mensagem de campo obrigatório não preenchido "Campo nome de preenchimento obrigatório" através de driver.getPageSource().contains("Campo nome de preenchimento obrigatório")

Eu estava querendo confirmar essa exibição dessa mensagem de campo obrigatório na tela após uma submissão de um WebElement.submit(); e o Test estava falhando, pois o assertTrue devia estar sendo executado antes da leitura da mensagem da PageSource. Então ao utilizar a Thread.sleep o assert conseguiu passar, veja como ficou o código:
...

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "your path\\geckodriver.exe"); //Eu tive problema com o Firefox, só depois que baixei o geckdriver e coloquei essa linha que consegui rodar o teste no Firefox

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("path of your webapp");

WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.name("nome do campo email por exemplo"));

email.sendKeys("xxxxx@xxxx.xxxx");
email.submit(); \\sem fornecer o nome que era obrigatório

// Thread.sleep(NUMBER_OF_MILLIS);
Thread.sleep(3000); //Sem essa linha o teste não funcionava
assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("Campo nome de preenchimento obrigatório"));

driver.close();
```

...